# Maintain state in react while using react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router

I am a beginner in React. Please help me out in this.
I am using react router(Link, Route, BrowserRouter, Switch) to navigate between different pages. I have set a state in one of the pages,when I navigate back to the previous page, the state is lost. Should I use redux for storing the state?

Comment: Can you provide us a example code of what you're trying to do?

Comment: yes, you can use redux if you want to store your application state into one place and state is lost because component is unmounted from DOM when you navigate back, that's why you loose your state data.

Answer (score 2):

Say you have 2 pages. These 2 pages have some internal state.
Now when you are traversing from Page A to Page B.

Page B states gets called beginning from `constructor` (if you are using class based components) till `componentDidMount`. So Page B has its states defined.

Now you are traversing back to Page A (via link or browser back), so Page A gets a **fresh call** and it starts calling its internal states and starts setting up the entire page.

So your previous states are now lost. To retain your states across you need to understand state management using [Redux](https://redux.js.org/basics/basic-tutorial).

PS: It is good that you start off with React Hooks and deep dive into Redux for state management.

Answer (score 0):

You should you react-redux you can't get state of another component, if you want to get the state from another component you can pass the state from component A as props to component B

**Ex:**

```
import componentB from "path_to_the_component_b"
```

Then you can pass state from component A to componentB by props like this

```
<componentB state={this.state.your_state_name}/>
```